# csv file is shown instead of downloaded

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I know there are many topics allready opened on this, however, I've tried everything without any success.

Here's my problem:

I've installed a plugin on opencart that is supposed to allow the admin to export the orders in XML, CSV, or Excel file. However, the browser opens the file instead of downloading it. The plugin works just fine on the demo page of the author. I asked the author if he had some clues for this problem, without any concrete answer. After trying a lot of possible solutions, I am starting to think that the problem may be caused by my server's settings.

The header looks like this :

```
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8');
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="orders-' . date('YmdHis') . ".{$fext}\"");
$content = (($fext == 'csv') ? mb_convert_encoding($this->render(), 'GBK', 'UTF-8') :
$this->render());
```

I've tried changing the Content-Type for text/csv, application/csv, application/octet-stream, and some others. Nothing does the trick.

In my .htaccess file, I've tried adding this code:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
```

And this one:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:xls|csv)$">
 Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Without any success either.

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe opencart does some header magic. Did you check which headers are *really* sent?

Comment: I just did, and it seems that you are right. On the firebug panel, it is written that the header sent is text/html. I wonder why...

Comment: Remove the stuff You have above from `.htaccess` and from virtual host definition (or `httpd.conf`). It is not needed at all since You set all the necessary settings in PHP code. It is enough to set the content-type, content-disposition with filename, optionally content-length. Unless You have installed an MS Office plugin for Your browser for MS Office documents (that they could be opened directly without the need of downloading them) it should work. Try different browsers and/or different computer. I guess it is working fine but on Your PC...

Answer (score 0):

After adding the headers, add this line below:

```
$this->response->setOutput($output);
```

The output variable should contain the csv string data. You could also try:

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

Not sure how your order export tool creates the csv based on your description, but hope this shines some light on the issue.